# Django custom backend causes error on signin

Tags: python, django

Wrote custom django backend, after clicking signin button it calls authenticate and fails with error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

I pushed string to authentication backend

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'app_auth.auth_backend.AuthBackend'
]
```

What may go wrong?

Stacktrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /sign-in/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\django-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\django-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\django-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\django-proj\app_auth\views.py", line 12, in sign_in
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
  File "C:\django-proj\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "C:\django-proj\app_auth\auth_backend.py", line 24, in authenticate
    user.backend = 'app_auth.auth_backend.AuthBackend'
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'backend'
[21/Feb/2019 22:53:20] "POST /sign-in/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78995
[21/Feb/2019 23:15:25] "GET /sign-in/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1274
```

Authenticate function

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from services.db.users import get_user, get_user_by_id

class AuthBackend():
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        user = get_user(username=username)
        return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        return get_user_by_id(id=user_id)
```

`get_user` and `get_user_by_id` return stub data

```
user = {
    'name': 'user-name',
    'backend': 'app_auth.auth_backend.AuthBackend'
}


def get_user(username):
    return user


def get_user_by_id(id):
    return user
```

Comment: Can you show the whole stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, added

Comment: Ok, can you show your `authenticate` function then? It seems that user is a dict instance, not your user model instance.

Comment: Added in question. Nothing special in this function for now, simplified to find the reason of error, still getting it...

Comment: Alright; why are you using `user` dictionary, instead of user model? E.g. `get_user_model().objects.get(username=username)`?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it possible then return UserModel from, for example, NoSQL request, (I mean not using django's db engines). Should I use something like this? :


`from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser`

`class User(AbstractUser):`

`pass`

Comment: It's definitely possible (see e.g. [mongo engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), however to entirely skip the django models and use e.g. dicts, you would have to alter more than just authentication backend from the built-in auth.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that in line 24 of authenticate you are setting
`user.backend = 'app_auth.auth_backend.AuthBackend'`, and that the dict does not have that attribute.

You are accessing the field incorrectly. If `user` is a dictionary and you want to set the value of an attribute called `backend` then your line 24 should be:

```
user['backend'] = 'app_auth.auth_backend.AuthBackend'
```